# Apache Camel: Publishing a CXF web service

Tags: java, apache-camel

Application is already using Camel to connect to few JMS queues and ESBs. Now I am trying to publish a CXF webservice with the help of camel. 

 Not sure what are the jars I have to include?

**Issue 1:**
I am getting `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: QUALIFIED
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.getOrCreateSchema`

**Issue 2:**
I have to add `cxf-2.7.5.jar`, `cxf-common-utilities-2.2.4.jar`, `camel-cxf-2.11.0.jar`,  `camel-cxf-transport-2.11.0`, `httpclient-4.2.1.jar`, `httpasyncclient-4.0-beta3.jar`, `httpcore-4.2.2.jar` and `httpcore-nio-4.2.2.jar` in my library folder.
 I am reluctant to add so many extra jars. Is there a common jar to implement cxf with camel. Looking for something like camelcxf-all.jar?
**Application Detail**
Application's context root is `PORTAL`. 

**CamelCXFInterface**

```
package webservice;

public interface CamelCXFInterface {

    public String sayHi(String doc);
}
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="routerEndpoint" address="http://localhost:15080/PORTAL/TryCXF"
            serviceClass="webservice.CamelCXFInterface"/>

<route>
    <from uri="cxf:bean:routerEndpoint"/>
    <to uri="stream:out"/>
</route>
```

Comment: Could you please post the definition of the routerEndpoint bean please, and whether or not you are making use of a container such as Karaf/servicemix/fuseesb etc

Comment: @AlanFoster I have resolved my previous issue. It was related to applicationContext.xml. Now I am stuck with these jars issues. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you use maven to manage the third part dependencies?
I think you should use maven, it will help you resolve lots of jars dependency issues.

I don't think you should put the cxf-common-utilities-2.2.4.jar into the class path if you are using CXF all in one jar.